# Adding emojis on to a script not working

Tags: bash, scripting

Hey folks I have the following script, where I just try to print an emoji, however when I execute the script I don't see the emoji, but when I do `printf emoji-utf-code` from the console it works. Am I missing something?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

UNICORN='\U1F984\n'

# this does not work when I run the script
printf ${UNICORN}
printf '\U1F984\n'
echo "Riding an ${UNICORN}"

# but when I type the printf command with the UTF-8 code in the console it works.
```

PS: How could I add a shell here so I could run the script? I have seen it on other posted questions.

**EDIT 1:** corrected code after some comments.

Still getting this on the console:

[image]

Comment: Hi @intercoder, welcome to U&L stackExchange.

Can you clarify what you mean by "adding a shell" please? What OS are you running this on?

Comment: @RobotJohnny I'm running on MacOS, by "adding a shell" I meant running my code on SO like in here 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet

but I don't see that option (button) on the editor.

Comment: Ah I see. As far as I'm aware, that's for `javascript`, `CSS` and `html` only. None of which are relevant in U&L hence why it isn't an option on this StackExchange

Comment: @RobotJohnnyI see, how do I added for javacript, etc? Thanks

Comment: the button highlighted in the answer you linked mentions how to do so https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet 

You can't do it on this stack exchange, but others such as stackoverflow you can.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> printf '\U1F984\n'
> ```

Versions 4.1 and earlier of the Bourne Again shell do not understand `\U` and `\u` escape sequences in the format argument of the built-in `printf` command.  To use them, you need version 4.2 or later.  This addition is in the Bourne Again shell's release notes for version 4.2, in 2011.

Alternatively, use the Z shell version 4.1.1 or later.  The Z shell gained this extension to `printf` several years earlier, in 2003.  The 93 Korn shell also has had this extension for some time.

You can of course convert the code point into UTF-8 and print the UTF-8 directly as a sequence of octal-encoded octets, which should work with any unextended standard-conformant `printf`:

```
printf '\360\237\246\204\n'
```

Comment: [$'...', echo, and printf understand \uXXXX and \UXXXXXXXX escape sequences.](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES)

Comment: Thanks @JdeBP that solved the problem, how does one escapes the variables declared as a string using `echo`. For example `My_VAR=''\360\237\246\204\n''` `echo Riding an ${UNICORN}` ?

Comment: Note that those `\uXXXX`/`\UXXXXXXXX` were first added in GNU `printf` (the standalone utility from coreutils not the builtin of the GNU shell), and first in `$'....'` in `zsh`. `$'\u...'`, `$'\U...'` is planned for inclusion in POSIX though the details are not fully sorted out as there are significant differences between existing implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-e` option with `echo`:

```
$ UNICORN='\U1F984'; THUMBS_UP='\U1F44D'; echo -e "Riding an ${UNICORN} (${THUMBS_UP})"
Riding an  ()
```

My `bash` doesn't seem to have the unicorn emoji, but the thumbs up should illustrate the concept.

Comment: `bash` neither knows nor cares about emoji. It's the terminal emulator and font that handle the representation of the character bytes into a symbol you can recognise.

Answer (score 1):

you have a space between your variable declaration and it's value:

`UNICORN= '\U1F984\n'`

Also note that `echo` will print the variable as a literal string rather than a utf-8 code's expected output

Lastly, it's a good idea to quote your variables. This is working for me on a fedora 25 box:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

UNICORN='\U1F984\n'

printf "${UNICORN}"
printf '\U1F984\n'
```

Comment: just tried it, but still get the same, posting a picture now.

Comment: It looks like your IDE is the problem; it probably can't handle utf8 emoji codes - if you run it via a normal shell terminal `cmd+space <type "terminal">` do you get the same output? Also I'm not sure if you replicating a zsh environment would cause any issues in your IDE either.

Comment: This answer seems outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Using perl:

```
perl -CO -E 'say "\N{U+1F984}"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `-e` to your `echo` statement to enable the extended processing of things like utf8 sequences and it will work
[image: screenshot of it working with the echo -e]

Comment: Note that the issue was with the version of the shell being installed on the user's system in 2018, or possibly with their `TERM` setting. Their code works as-is in a newer version of the shell on terminals that support displaying those types of glyphs. Also, note that `printf` is much safer and preferred over `echo`, and particularly over `echo -e`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Wellll…  Part of the problem was the bash version, and, yes, `printf` is generally better than `echo` or `echo -e`.  But, the question includes ``echo "Riding an ${UNICORN}"``, and that does not work in bash 4.3 — and ``echo -e "Riding an ${UNICORN}"`` does.  The bigger problem is that this duplicates [Jim Ivey’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/609037/80216).

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' You're correct, the plain `echo` would probably not work in a current `bash`, unless `xpg_echo` was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Put the expanded value in your variable with `$' '`, not the escaped representation:

```
UNICORN=$'\U1F984\n'
```

In most cases, it is a better idea to expand the actual characters as internal variable values, than to keep them escaped.

You verify that `echo -n $'\U1F984\n'` works as expected.